# Footer coming over flex box items.Not able to get footer at the page end of page. tried using grid and flex box. This is the code with grid

Tags: css, flexbox, grid, html4

after creating products using flexbox items, the footer which has a google map location and communication details, it is coming over the flexbox items having product images. I have tried using various solutions like:
1.Giving footer - margin-top:100% or 1000px; working, but issue comes back in Mobile mode.
2.creating display: flex column for all the items inside the body, using nav, main and footer tags(that code is not given here) and giving hem appropriate growth, shrink and basis values. it too didn't work.

reading various solutions from StackOverflow made it clear that using Grid is an effective solution.
I tried this code and it didn't work too. Please giver a feasible solution. Thanks in advance.

```
<head>

    <!-- Required meta tags -->

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    

    <title>SathaJeevana Ayur Foods</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="C:\Users\Durga siva prasad\Desktop\sathajeevana\images\logo.png" type="image/png" >
    
    <style>         
        
        
        .break {
          flex-basis: 100%;
          height: 0;
        }
        
                        html,body{
              height: 100%;
            }
            body{
              margin: 0;
            }
            body {
              display: grid;
              grid-gap: 10px;
              height: 100%;
              grid-template-columns:1fr;
              grid-template-areas:
                        "nav"
                        "main"
                        "footer";
              grid-template-rows: 100px 1fr 80px;
            }
            nav {
              grid-area: nav;
            }

            main {
              grid-area: main;
            }

            footer {
              grid-area: footer;
            }
                
    
    </style>
    
</head>

<body >
```

```
<a class="navbar-brand"><img src="C:\Users\Durga siva prasad\Desktop\sathajeevana\images\logo.png" type="image/png" height="70" width = "100" ></a>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center" id="nav">

    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

        <li class="nav-item" >

            <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold px-3" style="color: #008000" href="#">Home</a>

        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">

            <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold px-3" style="color: #008000" href="#">About Us</a>

        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">

            <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold px-3" style="color: #008000" href="#">Team</a>

        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">

            <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold px-3" style="color: #008000" href="#">Contact Us</a>

        </li>


        <li class="nav-item dropdown active" data-toggle="dropdown">

            <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold px-3  dropdown-toggle" style="color: #008000" href="#">Products</a>

                <div class="dropdown-menu">

                    <a class="dropdown-item font-weight-bold" style="color: #008000"  href="prodcol.html/#foodproducts" target="_self">Food Products</a>

                    <a class="dropdown-item font-weight-bold" style="color: #008000" href="prodcol.html/#oilproducts" target="_self">Oil Products</a>

                </div>

        </li>


    </ul>

</div>
```

```
<main>

    <a name="foodproducts"></a>

    <div class="d-flex justify-content-around align-items-center flex-wrap"  style="height: 500px;">
    
      <div class="p-4 m-2 border border-success   ">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="C:\Users\Durga siva prasad\Downloads\product and ingredients\SaltF.jpg" height="300" width = "200"  >
                <p class="font-weight-bold text-center" style="color: #008000" >Ayur 2 Salt</p>
            </a>
            <div class="text-center">
                <span><b>₹ 50</b></span><br>
                <span>Quantity: 1/2 kg<span><br><br>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        
      <div class=" p-4 m-2 border border-success  ">
        <a href="#">
                <img src="C:\Users\Durga siva prasad\Downloads\product and ingredients\MilletsF.jpg"  height="300" width = "200">
                <p class="font-weight-bold text-center" style="color: #008000">Ayur Millet Rice</p>
            </a>
            <div class="text-center">
                <span><b>₹ 50</b></span><br>
                <span>Quantity: 1/2 kg<span><br><br>
                <button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</button>
            </div>
      </div>

      <div class="break"></div> 

      <div class="p-4 m-2 border border-success   ">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="C:\Users\Durga siva prasad\Downloads\product and ingredients\Oil.jpg"  height="300" width = "700">
                <p class="font-weight-bold text-center" style="color: #008000" >Cooking Oil</p>
            </a>
            <div class="text-center">
                <span><b>₹ 50</b></span><br>
                <span>Quantity: 1/2 kg<span><br><br>    
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="break"></div> 
         
    <div>

</main>
```

```
    <footer id="footer">
        <div class="row">
        
            <div class="col-sm-8" id="map" style="height:400px; background:gray;"></div>
            
            <div class="col-sm-4 " style = " display: flex; align-items: center ; justify-content: center" >
                <p class=" font-weight-bold" style="text-align: center ">
                  <span style="color:green">Plot no: 12,<br>P.S.R. Colony,<br>Vizianagaram - 535002<br><br>
                  </span>
                    <span style="color:green">
                        8340979799 </br> 
                        <a href="mailto:sathajeevanafoods@gmail.com?cc=rvthridarmafoundation@gmail.com&subject=Enquiry%20regarding%20product%20from%20sathajeevana.in&body=I%20would%20like%20more%20information%20on%20product%20" target="_blank">sathajeevanafoods@gmail.com </a>
                    </span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

```
        <!-- jquery lib-->
                <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>

        <!-- bootstrap  -->

                <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <!--fontawesome-->

                <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-xymdQtn1n3lH2wcu0qhcdaOpQwyoarkgLVxC/wZ5q7h9gHtxICrpcaSUfygqZGOe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!--This is used for search icon. Instead putting icon manually it is loaded from fontawesome-->


            <!-- MAP scripts  -->
                    <script>
                    function myMap() {
                    var mapOptions = {
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng(18.1184,83.41799),
                        zoom: 10,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
                    }
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
                    }
                    </script>

                    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBu-916DdpKAjTmJNIgngS6HL_kDIKU0aU&callback=myMap"></script>



</body>
```

[image: Footer coming over flex-box content at middle of web page]

[image: page starting with navbar and some flex boxes]

Answer (score 0):

Probably it was covered by the main section, try and give the main section  z-index of 1 And the footer         z-index of 2.
Try it you see it appear some where and think of a logic to push it down. Or in alternative that you may add high margin-top let's say 1000px or anything else, you will see it appear.
It's there but it was overlaped by preceding codes.
Try it

Comment: main{ z-index:1;
 }
 Footer{ z-index:2;
 }

Comment: Hello Arman,I tried giving  body{ z-index:0;}   main{ z-index:1;  } Footer{ z-index:-2; }.  but all I got was main tag content is now visible over footer content. The footer is still under the main tag content.

Comment: I also tried giving margin-top:1000px.  it works fine in the desktop view. But, in the mobile view, it still has the problem. The content still overlaps with the main body content in the mobile view of the site.

Comment: Don't give the body z-index, the footer{z-index :2;}

Comment: Don't give z-index to the body and the footer's z-index value should be positive 2 not - 2 e.g footer{ z-index:2;}     always while applying z-index the element that you wanted to be at top must have highest value,

Comment: I did as you said, but it is still overlapping.   main{ 
    position:relative;
    z-index:1; } 
   
   
   #footer {
      z-index:2;
   }     I have given footer id="footer", thus the #